# project dotnet build error after adding target framework

Tags: .net, build

Opening this to document the error and solution, because error message was pretty opaque and I don't recall seeing it before for this cause.

Taking a nuget package targetting netcoreapp3.1 and forking it to target additional frameworks.   Upon building received this error:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Sequence contains no matching element [/home/user/work/src/nugetpkg/nuggetpkg.sln]

This error is typically a linq exception when a collection has no items but is attempted to be used.   Was surprised that it wasn't translated by compiler into a more context specific error (why I'm asking this question).

Answer (score 2):

Pretty non-informative build error, error doesn't even signify what the build is doing!

(perhaps adding a higher verbosity would have improved it, but still pretty low level error).

However since here since all I changed was target frameworks, I wondered if I had a typo.

Then recalled strange situation where microsoft defined multiple ways to target:

- one which works always
- and the other which only works when targetting a single framework.

this was the fix, change:

```
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

to:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

because the former only supports targetting one framework.

hopefully this helps somebody- or until microsoft makes these two forms behave the same.

Comment: Damn it, that one just got me too!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! God bless SO!